# Multiple rest calls to a service

Tags: scala, playframework, for-comprehension

I have to make multiple REST calls to a service to get information about multiple resources. Once all the resources information is available I need to join them in some way.

Can you please point me to the right Scala/play construct to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For REST client features on `Play`, there is rather detailed documentation in the [Play WS doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaWS).  You can chain your REST calls and process corresponding responses using a `for-comprehension` like in the following example, borrowed from this [Play WS section](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaWS#Chaining-WSClient-calls):

```
val futureResponse: Future[WSResponse] = for {
  responseOne <- ws.url(urlOne).get()
  responseTwo <- ws.url(responseOne.body).get()
  responseThree <- ws.url(responseTwo.body).get()
} yield responseThree

futureResponse.recover {
  case e: Exception =>
    val exceptionData = Map("error" -> Seq(e.getMessage))
    ws.url(exceptionUrl).post(exceptionData)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Future` composition via *for-comprehension*:

```
for {
  sugar      <- getSugar
  lemons     <- getLemons
  lemonJuice <- pressLemons(lemons)
  water      <- getWater
} yield {
  makeLemonade(sugar, lemonJuice, water)
}
```

Daniel Westheide has a great [tutorial](https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/09/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-8-welcome-to-the-future.html) on this.

Answer (score 0):

Explanations by Leo and Mario are quite sufficient but if you want more performant and parallel running code, you can refer to the below snippet:

```
def prepareCappuccino(): Future[Cappuccino] = {
  val groundCoffee = ws.url("url1").get()
  val heatedWater = ws.url("url2").get()
  val frothedMilk = ws.url("url3").get()

  for {
    ground <- groundCoffee
    water <- heatedWater
    foam <- frothedMilk
    espresso <- brew(ground, water)
  } yield combine(espresso, foam)
}
```

Defining your future calls like this enables each of the future calls to be executed in parallel threads asynchronously and it will run about `n-times` faster for n calls rather than using your calls directly in for comprehension.

This happens because for comprehension de-sugars to nested flat map and map calls and the pipeline formed results in blocking and sync API calls and scala has to interpret them as it is if you don't define your futures beforehand.

[Here](https://engineering.linkedin.com/play/play-framework-async-io-without-thread-pool-and-callback-hell) is an interesting article by Linked-in team who is responsible for play framework's development.

For web client usage you can easily look up in official [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaWS#Chaining-WSClient-calls).